# Android : Draw arc using gradient fill multiple color for analog clock

Tags: java, android

I want to draw an arc using multi-color based on the clock events logged by the user. (Say at 2pm and 8 pm, the event is logged, then I need to show an arc between 2pm and 8pm on an analog clock, using gradient and drawArc method of the canvas). How can the sweep angle be specified based on the time event?

Comment: I wouldn't define the angle before drawing an arc, I would calculate how long I have to draw the arc from 0, e.g. if it's from 2pm to 8pm, I'd draw it from 12 to 6 (or from wherever the un-angled arc is drawn) and then just rotate it so it matches the 2pm to 8pm

Comment: Thanks . But a small doubt , as sweepgradient method in android takes , startangle , sweepangle , int array (colors value) , float array [distribution value]  as parameters , how can we specify the distribution value accross it.